# Calculate the following limit without L'Hôpital's rule

Tags: limits, limits-without-lhopital

I need to calculate the following limit:

$$ \lim_{x\to3^+}\frac{\sqrt{x}-\sqrt{3}+\sqrt{x-3}}{\sqrt{x^2-9}} $$

I tried to multiply and divide by $\sqrt{x}-\sqrt{3}-\sqrt{x-3}$ but it didn't help me.

How can I calculate it?

Comment: Split the numerator into two parts

Answer (score 3):

Note that $\sqrt{x^2-9}=\sqrt{x+3}\sqrt{x-3}$ and that therefore\begin{align}\lim_{x\to3^+}\frac{\sqrt x-\sqrt3+\sqrt{x-3}}{\sqrt{x^2-9}}&=\lim_{x\to3^+}\left(\frac{\sqrt x-\sqrt3}{\sqrt{x+3}\sqrt{x-3}}+\frac1{\sqrt{x+3}}\right)\\&=\lim_{x\to3^+}\left(\sqrt{\frac{x-3}{x+3}}\frac{\sqrt x-\sqrt3}{x-3}+\frac1{\sqrt{x+3}}\right).\end{align}Now, use the fact that$$\lim_{x\to3^+}\frac{\sqrt x-\sqrt3}{x-3}=\frac1{2\sqrt3},$$since, if you differentiate $\sqrt x$, you get $\frac1{2\sqrt x}$.

Comment: You might want to note that $\lim_{x\to 3}\frac{\sqrt{x}-\sqrt{3}}{x-3}$ equals the derivative of the function $x\mapsto\sqrt{x}$ evaluated at $3$.

Comment: @Joe Nice suggestion. I've edited my answer. Thank you.

Comment: No. I get $1/{\sqrt6}$ consistent with both another answer and computations with MS Excel. Your final expression for the function seems to have the limit $1/\sqrt6$ but then $\sqrt6$ was mistaken for $2\sqrt3$. The latter is $\sqrt{12}$.

Comment: @OscarLanzi I get $\frac1{\sqrt6}$ too, since$$\lim_{x\to3^+}\left(\sqrt{\frac{x-3}{x+3}}\frac{\sqrt x-\sqrt3}{x-3}+\frac1{\sqrt{x+3}}\right)=0\times\frac1{2\sqrt3}+\frac1{\sqrt6}=\frac1{\sqrt6}.$$

Comment: But, $\sqrt6\not=2\sqrt3$.

Comment: @OscarLanzi Sorry. I though that you were talking about the original limit. Now I see that you're talking about$$\lim_{x\to3^+}\frac{\sqrt x-\sqrt3}{x-3}.$$But\begin{align}\lim_{x\to3^+}\frac{\sqrt x-\sqrt3}{x-3}&=\lim_{x\to3^+}\frac{\sqrt x-\sqrt3}{\left(\sqrt x-\sqrt3\right)\left(\sqrt x-\sqrt3\right)}\\&=\lim_{x\to3^+}\frac1{\sqrt x+\sqrt3}\\&=\frac1{2\sqrt3}.\end{align}

Comment: I misread. It looked like you were rendering $1/2\sqrt3$ as the answer.

Answer (score 2):

$$ \frac{\sqrt{x}-\sqrt{3}+\sqrt{x-3}}{\sqrt{x^2-9}} =\frac {\sqrt {x-3}} {\sqrt {x+3} (\sqrt x +\sqrt 3)}+\frac 1 {\sqrt {x+3}} \to \frac  1 {\sqrt 6} $$

Comment: How did you get to the first fraction?

Comment: @Dani $\sqrt {x^{2}-9}=\sqrt {x-3} \sqrt {x+3}$. Multiply numerator and denominator by $\sqrt x +\sqrt 3$.

Answer (score 0):

Multiplying the numerator and denominator by a conjugate is a good approach, but the multiplier should have a nonzero limit in order to avoid introducing additional zero factors. Here your chosen multiplier $\sqrt x-\sqrt3-\sqrt{x-3}$ fails that requirement.

Instead rearrange the numerator to read $\sqrt x+\sqrt{x-3}-\sqrt3$, and conjugate the nonzero $\sqrt3$ term so your multiplier is $\sqrt x+\sqrt{x-3}+\sqrt3$. This leads to

$\dfrac{\sqrt x+\sqrt{x-3}-\sqrt3}{\sqrt{x^2-9}}=\dfrac{(\sqrt x+\sqrt{x-3})^2-3}{\sqrt{x^2-9}(\sqrt x+\sqrt{x-3}+\sqrt3)}=\dfrac{2x-6+2\sqrt x\sqrt{x-3}}{\sqrt{x^2-9}(\sqrt x+\sqrt{x-3}+\sqrt3)}$

Then with $x^2-9=(x+3)(x-3)$ and $2x-6=2(x-3)$, we cancel out a factor of $\sqrt{x-3}$ leaving a denominator that no longer $\to0$ as $x\to3$. We then substitute accordingly:

$\dfrac{2\sqrt{x-3}+2\sqrt x}{\sqrt{x+3}(\sqrt x+\sqrt{x-3}+\sqrt3)}\to\dfrac{2\sqrt3}{\sqrt6(2\sqrt3)}=\color{blue}{\dfrac1{\sqrt6}}.$